# New Ubuntu, combining two separate primary partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

As you can see in the below screenshot, my partitions are essentially empty.

[image]

I just installed Ubuntu today, I had created a brand new partition to support my Ubuntu OS. However, after it successfully partitioned itself my Windows 7 partition no longer works at all. At this point I do not care about restoring my Windows 7 OS, I just want to combine my much larger currently unallocated partition of +600GB with my new Ubuntu partition. I have installed GParted and read other forums on the issue. However, whenever I try what they have suggested (as far as I can tell) resize/move only adjusts the size of the current partition. It has nothing to do with combining two separate partitions (which are both primary). Many other suggestions wanted me to delete the partition with the file system on it. I can't do that because that is the file system that I am currently using so it won't let me delete it.

I can't think of what to do. I am seriously worried that I have ruined my computer.

Comment: If brand new install, may be easier just to start over. Default install is / (root) and swap. But I prefer added partitions. I typically make / only 25GB, but put all data in another partition. For newer users that can be /home which you make during install using Something Else install option. If you want to edit partitions, you have to use gparted on live installer or create gparted live ISO flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go...

**FIRST, backup any data on sda3 and sda4!**

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start `gparted`

1. right-click on partition sda4 and **delete** it
2. right-click on partition sda3 and select **move/resize**
3. place the mouse pointer in the center of the partition, and the icon will change to a hand
4. **drag** the partition all the way to the left
5. **drag** the partition's RIGHT HANDLE all the way to the right
6. click the APPLY icon
7. reboot, and restore any sda4 data to sda3